# How we can integrate Elastic search in yii2 project

Tags: elasticsearch

How do we implement *elastic search* in **yii2**. Done with installation, How do I search by database using elastic search?

This is my *config file*:

```
'components' => [
    'elasticsearch' => [
        'class' => 'yii\elasticsearch\Connection',
        'nodes' => [
        ['http_address' => '127.0.0.1:80'],

        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,  I new to this concept. I created yii2 project in localhost and tried to implement elastic search on that. Is it possible to implement elastic search in localhost project?

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below link give u some idea about it

http://voormedia.com/blog/2014/06/four-ways-to-index-relational-data-in-elasticsearch